# Calling jquery method from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wheel-menu

I found a working code which calls a jquery function from javascript.I wanted to do the same on page load.Here below is my code.

```
    $(".wheel-button").wheelmenu({
    trigger: "",
    animation: "fly",
    animationSpeed: "fast"
    });
```

Please help me to call the wheelmenu() jquery function on page load with attributes.

Comment: Looks like `wheelmenu` is a plugin in which case, it's only meant to be called from a jQuery object.

Comment: yes,wheelmenu is a function in jquery.wheelmenu.js.i wanted that code to be executed on page load or after an element with id #center has been visible.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function run(){

 $(".wheel-button").wheelmenu({
    trigger: "",
    animation: "fly",
    animationSpeed: "fast"
    });
}
run();
});
```

That's it..

Comment: This code is getting closer to my need.since i am a beginner in jquery can u pls take a look at jquery.wheelmenu.js

Answer (score 2):

Use the "ready" event handler. It fires once the document has fully loaded.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $(".wheel-button").wheelmenu({
    trigger: "",
    animation: "fly",
    animationSpeed: "fast"
    });
});
```

See the ready function here:

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

Try the `short hand` of [$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)  `$( handler )` like,

```
$(function() {
   $(".wheel-button").wheelmenu({
      trigger: "",
      animation: "fly",
      animationSpeed: "fast"
   });
});
```